# How to configure codemirror for C-like language?

Tags: c, codemirror

I am using codeMirror in my wordpress site to highlight syntax C-like code. I have added all code js and css files as suggested:

```
/code-mirror/plugin/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css
/code-mirror/plugin/codemirror/lib/codemirror.js
/code-mirror/plugin/codemirror/theme/eclipse.css
/code-mirror/plugin/codemirror/addon/edit/matchbrackets.js
/code-mirror/js/c-like.js
```

Here c-like.js is my custom js file having the following code:

```
var cEditor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("c-code"), {
       lineNumbers: true,
       matchBrackets: true,
       mode: "text/x-csrc",
       readOnly: true,
       styleActiveLine: true,
       theme: "eclipse"
     });
```

but a simple C program is looks like:

[image]

There is no style at keywords like 'int' or #include. I am struggling to highlight C code as like CodeBlock syntax. Here is the live url: [codingpractise.com/c-code](http://bangla.codingpractise.com/%E0%A6%B8%E0%A6%BF-%E0%A6%AA%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%B0%E0%A7%8B%E0%A6%97%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%AE%E0%A6%BF%E0%A6%82/%E0%A6%AA%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%A5%E0%A6%AE-%E0%A6%B8%E0%A6%BF-%E0%A6%AA%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%B0%E0%A7%8B%E0%A6%97%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%AE/#eclipse). Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have forgot the `clike.js` not the one with your code but with the c mode

hosted by cdnjs: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.42.2/mode/clike/clike.min.js

DEMO: https://codepen.io/quic5/pen/ebMKNV